# How to restart JavaHost process?

Tags: java, linux

I had come across one problem and hence got solution [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/BIMIG/GUID-D6038515-9AA2-4F29-8330-D68EADD058A1.htm#BIMIG-GUID-D6038515-9AA2-4F29-8330-D68EADD058A1) but it asks to restart JavaHost process.

I am unable to find what JavaHost process exactly is and hence how to restart it on LInux. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use stop and start scripts to restart.

```
./stop.sh | stop.cmd {-i <list of instances>} {-c}
./start.sh | start.cmd {-noprompt} {-i <list of instances>}
```

check [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIESG/GUID-6543ADEA-8161-4C90-9AEA-A132C292D2EE.htm#BIESG9260) for more details